# How to I change a Table Header for each Page

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have been asked to make an XSLT transformation using `XSL-FO` to create Printable Reports from a Database. All so far is well and dandy, but there is one part of the Report that is causing some trouble.

Within the `fo:table-header` object, I need something that will change it, based on the rows that were displayed on that particular page. There is a Title in the header which needs to reflect the most recent Title of the current Group being displayed (just a change in an ordered text field from the database query). Currently, there are only two types of grouping, Incoming Messages and Outgoing Messages.

So, lets assume there are 10 Messages in the Incoming Group, and 20 Messages in the Outgoing Group, and the Printer can only fit 8 Messages on a Page.

The First Page will have the Title "Incoming Messages", then the first 8 Messages. Then the second page will start with the Title "Incoming Messages", return the remaining two Messages, then (this bit I know how to do), shows a Title row that indicates it has now moved onto the "Outgoing Messages". Again, the first 6 Messages will be shown on that page, then all the remaining pages will have the title "Outgoing Messages".

I hope that describes what I am trying to achieve. My thoughts are currently with storing the code to do this within the `table-header` as I can not find any way to detect a page jump within the `table-body`'s foreach loop.

If anyone has a better idea, please pipe up, but if there is a viable solution using this method, that would be fantastic.

**PS**

If there is a wholey divisible number of Messages to the number of Message per Page, then the next page will not lead with the previous group, as there are no more Messages in that Group.

Also, although currently there are only two groups, there have been talks about dividing the groups up even more groups, to as many as 8 in this case, but I'm sure they will be wanting more in the future.

**EDIT**

I am using Apache FOP as my XSL-FO processor, and I am outputting to PDF.

The data yielded from the query looks like:

```
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| ID | DR  | SNDR | RCVR | DT     | MSGCHK |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| 2  | IN  | 13   | 19   | 131201 | ...... |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| 4  | IN  | 13   | 17   | 131205 | ...... |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| 1  | OUT | 19   | 32   | 131119 | ...... |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| 3  | OUT | 19   | 17   | 131203 | ...... |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
| 5  | OUT | 17   | 16   | 131204 | ...... |
+----+-----+------+------+--------+--------+
```

The result has been ordered by `DIR` ASC and by `DT` DESC. So, my transformation currently checks the sibling element, and if it is different, it outputs a row with a colspan that encompasses an entire row with the new Direction in. For example:

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Receiver | Sender | Date   | Message Checksum |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Incoming Messages:                            |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 13       | 19     | 131201 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 13       | 17     | 131205 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Outgoing Messages:                            |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 19       | 32     | 131119 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 19       | 17     | 131203 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 17       | 16     | 131204 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

But what I am trying to do is, lets say you only get 3 messages per page, you would get:

Page 1:

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Receiver | Sender | Date   | Message Checksum |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Incoming Messages:                            |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 13       | 19     | 131201 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 13       | 17     | 131205 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Outgoing Messages:                            |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 19       | 32     | 131119 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

Page 2:

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Receiver | Sender | Date   | Message Checksum |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| Outgoing Messages:                            |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 19       | 17     | 131203 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
| 17       | 16     | 131204 | ......           |
+----------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

It currently does something similar to this, except, for page 2, the title saying `Outgoing Messages` is not present

Comment: This question is reasonable, but as yet too conceptual. Please add an input sample from your database (XML) and relevant parts of your XSL-FO code. Also, say what format you are transforming to (PDF?) and which FO processor you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Is it inevitable that all the rows are output in one single table? Why not split the tables into an `Incoming Messages` and `Outgoing Messages` one? (Besides, it is _really_ difficult to help you without seeing actual XSL-FO code.)

Comment: Well, I could do that, but I have no idea as to how to calculate how many rows can fit into a page after the paper size, the margins, headers, and footers have been taken into account. Having to result queries isn't really an option. The system is designed so that when you request a report, a stored operation populates a temporary table with the data, and a cursor for the temporary information is then parsed to the Transformer for it to iterate through all the rows and apply the fields. Presently, the FO code is just a header, a foreach loop to parse the results into the body, and a footer.

Comment: Unless I am not understanding something, that is easy. That is a table with repeating header with one column, cell and inside it is other tables that also have repeating headers.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a solution for the case the number of header rows in page can be ignored. This is, of course, a little ugly since the header rows also take up space but it's a first approach and the special cases for counting the number of header lines in the document up to a certain row is really tedious (think of the case in which a group has exactly the size of a page!).

What needs to be done is compute the header line based on the page size *and* the detection of a new group. To make this clearer the XSLT has local variables declared for clarity.

Assuming we have the following simplified input (you have to bear with my ignorance of XSL-FO)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rows>
  <row id="1" type="in"/>
  <row id="2" type="in"/>
  <row id="3" type="out"/>
  <row id="4" type="out"/>
  <row id="5" type="out"/>
  <row id="6" type="up"/>
  <row id="7" type="down"/>
  <row id="8" type="down"/>
</rows>
```

using this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="pagesize" select="3"/>

  <xsl:template match="rows">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="pagebreak" select="(count(preceding-sibling::row) mod $pagesize = 0) and count(preceding-sibling::row)>1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new_group" select="(preceding-sibling::row)[last()]/@type != @type or count(preceding-sibling::row)=0"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pagebreak">
      <pagebreak/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$pagebreak or $new_group">
      <header type="{@type}"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <tr id="{@id}" type="{@type}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <header type="in"/>
  <tr id="1" type="in"/>
  <tr id="2" type="in"/>
  <header type="out"/>
  <tr id="3" type="out"/>
  <pagebreak/>
  <header type="out"/>
  <tr id="4" type="out"/>
  <tr id="5" type="out"/>
  <header type="up"/>
  <tr id="6" type="up"/>
  <pagebreak/>
  <header type="down"/>
  <tr id="7" type="down"/>
  <tr id="8" type="down"/>
</table>
```